# Java DateFormat parse() doesn't respect the timezone

Tags: java, parsing, date, format

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));

try {
    System.out.println(df.format(cal.getTime()));
    System.out.println(df.parse(df.format(cal.getTime())));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here is the result:

> 2011-09-24 14:10:51 -0400
>
> Sat Sep 24 20:10:51 CEST 2011

Why when I parse a date I get from format() it doesn't respect the timezone?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You're printing the result of calling [`Date.toString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29), which *always* uses the default time zone. Basically, you shouldn't use `Date.toString()` for anything other than debugging.

Don't forget that a `Date` doesn't *have* a time zone - it represents an instant in time, measured as milliseconds since the Unix epoch (midnight on January 1st 1970 UTC).

If you format the date using your formatter again, *that* should come up with the same answer as before.

As an aside, I would recommend the use of [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead of `Date`/`Calendar` if you're doing any significant amount of date/time work in Java; it's a *much* nicer API.

Comment: That's right...try printing `System.out.println(df.format(df.parse(df.format(cal.getTime()))));` and it works as expected :-)

Comment: Ok so apparently the problem comes from the toString()? Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @MaximeLaval: From `Date.toString` in particular, yes - and you need to be aware that a `Date` is just an instant, not in any particular time zone or calendar.

Comment: Never rely on a `.toString` method for something other than displaying/debugging. Also note that SimpleDateFormatter is Locale sensitive.

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy: Unless the behaviour is documented to do what you want, of course.

Comment: @JonSkeet, what I meant was that for your custom code it is often better not to have a rigid `toString` as you may want to change that `toString` method later on. Usually I provide something like `asText` and call that from the `toString` and critical code uses `asText` but never `toString`. In case the `toString` should not be modified it must indeed be documented as such...

Answer (score 7):

`DateFormat.parse()` is NOT a query (something that returns a value and doesn't change the state of the system).  It is a command which has the side-effect of updating an internal `Calendar` object.  After calling `parse()` you have to access the timezone either by accessing the `DateFormat`'s `Calendar` or calling `DateFormat.getTimeZone()`.  Unless you want to throw away the original timezone and use local time, do not use the returned `Date` value from `parse()`.  Instead use the calendar object after parsing.  And the same is true for the format method.  If you are going to format a date, pass the calendar with the timezone info into the `DateFormat` object before calling `format()`.  Here is how you can convert one format to another format preserving the original timezone:

```
    DateFormat originalDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
    DateFormat targetDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE., MMM. dd, yyyy");

    originalDateFormat.parse(origDateString);
    targetDateFormat.setCalendar(originalDateFormat.getCalendar());
    return targetDateFormat.format(targetDateFormat.getCalendar().getTime());
```

It's messy but necessary since `parse()` doesn't return a value that preserves timezone and `format()` doesn't accept a value that defines a timezone (the `Date` class).

Answer (score 2):

> DateFormat is an abstract class for date/time formatting subclasses
>   which formats and parses dates or time in a language-independent
>   manner. The date/time formatting subclass, such as SimpleDateFormat,
>   allows for formatting (i.e., date -> text), parsing (text -> date),
>   and normalization. **The date is represented as a Date object or as the
>   milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT**.

From the [spec](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html), it return EPOCH time

Answer (score 2):

A `java.util.Date` object is not a real Date-Time object like the [modern Date-Time types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html); rather, it represents the number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely `January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT` (or UTC). Since it does not hold any format and timezone information, it applies the format, `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy` and the JVM's timezone to return the value of `Date#toString` derived from this milliseconds value. If you need to print the Date-Time in a different format and timezone, you will need to use a `SimpleDateFormat` with the desired format and the applicable timezone e.g.

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH);
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
String strDate = sdf.format(date);
System.out.println(strDate);
```

Note that the `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

### Solution using `java.time`, the modern API:

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
        System.out.println(zdt);

        // With timezone offset
        OffsetDateTime odt = zdt.toOffsetDateTime();
        System.out.println(odt);

        // In a custom format
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String formatted = dtf.format(odt);
        System.out.println(formatted);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-06-04T14:25:08.266940-04:00[America/New_York]
2021-06-04T14:25:08.266940-04:00
2021-06-04 14:25:08 -0400
```

Here, you can use `yyyy` instead of `uuuu` but [I prefer `u` to `y`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65928023/10819573).

Learn more about `java.time`, the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>